# Plotly Dash URL pathname callback not firing when loading page

Tags: python, flask, callback, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a multi-page Dash app using the url callback. My app called dash_apps.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    server = server,
    serve_locally = False,
    requests_pathname_prefix = "/plotary/dash/",
)

app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div([
        html.A([
            html.Div(id="logo")
        ],href='https://man-es.com'),
        html.Div([
            html.H1('Keine Auswertung ausgewählt. ')
        ],id="description"),
    ],
    id="navbar")]
)

@app.callback(Output('description', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    return html.Div([
        html.H1('Auswertung Nr {}'.format(pathname))
    ])

@server.route('/plotary/dash/<int:report_id>')
def create_report(report_id):
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and is called through a wsgi.py that looks like this:

```
from dash_apps import server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run()
```

The server I am using runs nginx and I use a web socket that starts wsgi.py with gunicorn as is explained in [this post](https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a).

Now if I open for example `http://<ip.to.server>/plotary/dash/18` it will just state `Keine Auswertung ausgewählt.` although I would expect it to show `Auswertung Nr. 18`.

What am I missing here?

Alternatively I could also get the `report_id` from Flask's `route`, however I do not know how to then pass this variable to `app.layout`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `dcc.Location` object  to your layout, and its `id` should match the one you are using on the callback ("url" in the case of `Input('url', 'pathname')`).

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div([
    html.A([
        html.Div(id="logo")
    ],href='https://man-es.com'),
    html.Div([
        html.H1('Keine Auswertung ausgewählt. ')
    ],id="description"),
],
id="navbar")]
)
```

Comment: Wow that was a rapid answer! I will accept it as soon as I'm allowed to (~5 minutes).